# Translating Python print statements to Django

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of creating a Django web application that reads a URL and outputs selected data from the page. I have written the code in Python that parses the web page and it currently returns the information that I need to display in the Django app as desired.

Before I dive in I just want to confirm what I have researched is correct as I only have a limited time to complete the project.

To summarise my python code, it is in the src folder in a class called "manage.py"

I have created print statements that print the information that I need to display (I did this to ensure it was returning the correct data)

```
print(variable1)

print("some text" + variable2)
```

Can I create the Django app code in the same file, "manage.py"? (The project has already been created as a Django app in Eclipse when I started building the project)

Would I build the Django code as I've estimated below if I'm using the variables defined from the Python code above?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Title of website{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Web page report</h1>

    <h2>Summary of web page</h2>

    <h3>Title of document</h3>
    <p>{{variable1}}</p>

    <h3>The file size of the document</h3>
    <p>{"Some text" + {variable2}}</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has strict rules about where to place which information. You can not write everything into manage.py. Answering requests from the browser is for example done using view functions.